# Share of Whatsapp and facebook along with text and image

Tags: android, facebook

I wanted to share my image to social site along with textlink and image , I am using below code , it does share Image but no text , Also I tried to set setype to "text/html" , it does not does what i need.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "http://www.google.com");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
    pDialog.dismiss();

}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to specify the message part of any share for the user, they have to type it in themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(Filepath);
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My sample image text");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    try {
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Kindly install whatsapp first");
    }
```

> PS: For sharing in multiple apps just create an alert dialogue and add
>   whtsapp,fb and other sharing option and while clicking on them you
>   have to call specific intent for this.As per my knowledge  for sharing
>   in facebook you must impliment it's sdk, though facebook is able to
>   share simple image and hyperlink without integrating sdk.

Comment: Thanks does work , but what if I had provide user with an option that it can share via whatsapp fb or any other media

Comment: @SujitSoni Kindly check my edited answer for sharing in  multiple apps